# If $|f|$ is differentiable then is $f$ differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $|f|$ is differentiable then is $f$ differentiable?

I know that if $f$ is differentiable then $|f|$ may not be

Example $f(x)=x$

But how to do the converse?

Comment: I deleted this question bcs I found answer to this question ;it is still active;;; Why so?

Answer (score 9):

The function $f$ defined to be $1$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $-1$ on $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ is such that $|f|$ is differentiable but not $f$.